# Get polygons from google map

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3, geolocation

I have a kml file with a bunch of polygons. I manged to create a google map and load this kml following the documentation.

```
(function initMap() {
        var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
          zoom: 11,
          center: {lat: 41.876, lng: -87.624}
        });

        var ctaLayer = new google.maps.KmlLayer({
          url: 'http://myurl.dev/polygons.kml',
          map: map
        });

})();
```

Now, I want to retrieve all the polygons from this kml in order the ask if a point (lat,long) is within some of them.

```
google.maps.geometry.poly.containsLocation(point, OnePolygonFromMyMap);
```

The problem, is that I did not find any documentation to get all the shapes the map contains. Is this possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't access the polygons on the map when they are placed there using KmlLayer, [google.maps.KmlLayer](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference#KmlLayer) is uses tile based rendering, you can't (at least at present) access the coordinates of the polygons except on a click.

Note however that rendering the polygons as native google.maps.Polygon objects (as the third party libraries do) could have a performance penalty, particularly if your KML is complex.

You could use a third party KML parser like [geoxml3](https://github.com/geocodezip/geoxml3/) or [geoxml-v3](https://code.google.com/p/geoxml-v3/) to render the polygons as native google.maps.Polygon objects, and get their center.  This will have performance issues with complex KML.

[example using geoxml3](http://www.geocodezip.com/geoxml3_test/v3_geocodePointInPolygon_linkto.html)